# Tesseract OCR with fix template based forms (like Passport)

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to perform OCR with tesseract. I need to extract metadata based on template form (kind of passport example where we have fix place for first name, date of birth, etc).

So my basic questions :

1. Is this possible using tesseract? If so how can I achieve this?
2. Can we define a template to tesseract-OCR?
3. Can we identify the handwritten and printed sections separately?
4. Can we get a confidence level only for the handwritten section?

Comment: If you are having issues implementing this with Tesseract, you might want to try a commercial library such as the Leadtools SDK: https://www.leadtools.com. This has a section of toolkits specifically designed for matching images to a predefined template and then extracting values based on the coordinates set in the template. You can extract printed text, barcodes, OMR fields, and even handwritten text and parsed MRZ. As a disclaimer, I work for this vendor.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it possible to do this:**

take an example with python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import os
import argparse

# Configuration
per = 25
roi = [
    [(880, 128), (1496, 252), 'text', 'title'],
    [(314, 592), (596, 666), 'text', 'reference'],
    [(232, 674), (572, 718), 'text', 'date'],
    [(240, 732), (562, 774), 'text', 'clientId'],
    [(1234, 1298), (1506, 1380), 'text', 'total'],
    [(1222, 1382), (1504, 1454), 'text', 'tva'],
    [(1234, 1460), (1510, 1536), 'text', 'totaltcc']]

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/bin/tesseract'

def process_invoices(query_image, invoice_folder):
    imgQ = cv2.imread(query_image)
    h, w, c = imgQ.shape

    orb = cv2.ORB_create(1000)
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(imgQ, None)

    listInvoices = os.listdir(invoice_folder)

    results = []

    for j, y in enumerate(listInvoices):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(invoice_folder, y))
        kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
        matches = bf.match(des2, des1)
        matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
        good = matches[:int(len(matches) * (per / 100))]

        srcPoints = np.float32([kp2[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dstPoints = np.float32([kp1[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        M, _ = cv2.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        imgScan = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (w, h))

        imgShow = imgScan.copy()
        imgMask = np.zeros_like(imgShow)

        myData = []
        for x, r in enumerate(roi):
            border_color = (0, 0, 255)  # Red border color
            border_thickness = 2

            cv2.rectangle(imgMask, (r[0][0] - border_thickness, r[0][1] - border_thickness),
                          (r[1][0] + border_thickness, r[1][1] + border_thickness), border_color, -1)
            imgShow = cv2.addWeighted(imgShow, 0.99, imgMask, 0.1, 0)

            imgCrop = imgScan[r[0][1]:r[1][1], r[0][0]:r[1][0]]

            if r[2] == "text":
                value = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgCrop)
                if "," in value:
                    value = value.replace(",", ".")  # Remove comma from amount

                myData.append(f'{r[3]}: {value}')

        results.append((y, myData))

    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Invoice OCR')
    parser.add_argument('query_image', type=str, help='Path to the query image')
    parser.add_argument('invoice_folder', type=str, help='Path to the folder containing invoice images')
    parser.add_argument('--output_file', type=str, default='dataInvoices.csv', help='Path to the output CSV file')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    results = process_invoices(args.query_image, args.invoice_folder)

    with open(args.output_file, 'w') as f:
        for invoice_name, data in results:
            f.write(f'Invoice: {invoice_name}\n')
            for item in data:
                f.write(f'{item}\n')
            f.write('\n')

    for invoice_name, data in results:
        print(f'Invoice: {invoice_name}')
        for item in data:
            print(item)
        print('\n')
```

run script using command line :

```
python3 main.py query.jpg [path folder container images need]
```

this some references: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9oRTI6mLnU&t=300s

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**